# How to Import Data from .DBF file to Some Other Database like ElevateDB?

Tags: c#, sql, database, dbf, elevatedb

I have large file say named as "customers" and it is in .DBF format. Now I want to import that .DBF file data to ElevateDB database. ,,,Is ther any ways to import data by Query or write program for import from .DBF to ElevateDB...

Answer (score 0):

If you have Access at your disposal, and the table structures are similar, it should be quite easy.

As ElevateDB seems to have an ODBC driver you should be able to access the DB via the [linked tables](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tables/link_table2007.php) feature, and Access can also manipulate DBF files.  It's been a long time since I had to do such a transfer, but once you have the ODBC driver in place it's simple.